# Validating a given date if it falls on a weekend

Tags: oracle

Is there any better approach than the function code below

```
// checks whether the IN data falls on a weekend 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION business_days(start_date IN DATE)
   RETURN NUMBER IS
busdays NUMBER := 0;
stDate DATE;

BEGIN

stDate := TRUNC(start_date);

  /* Adjust for ending date on a saturday */
  IF  TO_CHAR(enDate,'D') = '7'    THEN
    busdays := busdays - 1;
  END IF;

  /* Adjust for starting date on a sunday */
  IF TO_CHAR(stDate,'D') = '1' THEN
    busdays := busdays - 1;
  END IF;
else
   busdays := 0;
END IF;

  RETURN(busdays);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, days of the week starts with Monday (which corresponds to 1); therefore if you are to find whether a day falls into weekend you need to compare it with number 6 and 7 (corresponding to Saturday and Sunday) such as:

```
if to_char(prmDate,'D') not in (6,7) then
    --weekend...
```

Furthermore, extracting day (in number format) from date and comparing whether it's '6' or '7' seems like the only option to understand if it's a weekday or weekend and that works just fine.

Comment: @A.B.Cade true, the value returned from the `to_char(some_date, 'D')` depends on the timezone which is determined by `NLS_TERRITORY`. Yet he should be doing the same 6 and 7'th day control to determine whether it's a weekend or a weekday independent of the timezone.

Comment: if to_char(prmDate,'D') not in (6,7) then prmDate:= prmDate -1; this should give be fridays date right ?

Comment: No, you cannot retrieve Friday like that because 'D' is never equal to '6' (Saturday). You can set your date to Friday when it's weekend as the following way:
`if to_char(prmDate,'D') = 6 then 
   prmDate:= prmDate -1;
else if to_char(prmDate,'D') = 7 then 
   prmDate:= prmDate -2;`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with one query:

According to the post's title you want something like:

```
select case when to_char(start_date, 'D') in ('7', '1') then -1 else 0 end
    from dual
```

According to your code example I'd think you want:

```
select case 
         when to_char(start_date, 'D') = '7' and to_char(end_date, 'D') ='1' then -2 
         when to_char(start_date, 'D') = '7' or to_char(end_date, 'D') ='1' then -1 
         else 0 end
from dual
```